# mod_rewrite rewritebase current directory

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have folder /thesite/ with all php files. I have /.htaccess in the root directory. Inside of .htaccess there rules like:

`RewriteEngine on`

RewriteRule ^thesite/([^/]+)/$ thesite/code.php?data=$1

I want to move this htaccess into thesite directory and don't methion directory name anywhere inside of htaccess, so that i can rename or move this directory freely. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

this does exactly that, through it looks too scary to use http://www.zeilenwechsel.de/it/articles/8/Using-mod_rewrite-in-.htaccess-files-without-knowing-the-RewriteBase.html

googled by mod_rewrite htaccess directory current directory